# Using wheelDelta on IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, scroll, parallax, microsoft-edge

So I made a page that uses parallax scrolling. The parallax is working smoothly on Chrome and firefox, but on IE it started stuttering. So I made (by that I mean googled) this script that **fixed it on Edge and IE10**

```
    if(navigator.userAgent.match(/(?:\b(MS)?IE\s+|\bTrident\/7\.0;.*\s+rv:|\bEdge\/)(\d+)/)) {
        jQuery('body').on("mousewheel", function () {
            // remove default behavior
            event.preventDefault();

            //scroll without smoothing
             var wheelDelta = event.wheelDelta;
             var currentScrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;
             window.scrollTo(0, currentScrollPosition - wheelDelta);
        });
}
```

But it completely broke scrolling on IE11. 
It's really strange that it works on IE10 and edge but not on IE11.

Anyone know what might be a fix for that problem? I imagine that addeventlistener would help, but I didnt manage to implement it correctly.

Would really appreciate the help!!

**EDIT: On EDGE the zooming is broken too. Is that inevitable?**

Comment: `mousewheel` is deprecated, use `wheel` instead, it works in IE11 and Edge, as well as in all modern browsers. Forget browser detection, especially in case of Edge. Detect the feature, and fall back to `mousewheel` only when `wheel` isn't supported.

Comment: @Teemu using 'wheel' does'nt change anything. Also I know that browser detection isnt the best solution, but what feature I would need to detect, when it works perfectly on chrome and firefox..

Comment: ?? Pseudo: `if (window.wheel) {/* attach wheel */} else {/* attach mousewheel */}`.

Comment: @Teemu I mean I want to fix the parallax stuttering. The disabled scrolling issue comes with the parallax fix. Maybe I dont get the right point here but why would I detect window.wheel? Does IE11 use window.wheel and other browsers use just wheel?

Comment: Just apply your knowledge to feature detection. "Stuttering" is probably fixed by normalizing the value of `deltaY` of the _wheel event_ object. In Edge you'll get something near 60 as in FF it's only 3 (depends on the mouse settings of the machine). Hence `var delta = e.deltaY / Math.abs(e.deltaY) * 3;` 3, or what ever best suits for your purposes.

Comment: @Teemu By stuttering I mean that the parallax images are jumpy and not smooth when scrolling. It is "jumpy" when I dont use the script I posted in my question, it is though with the default scrolling. The javascript I posted actually fixed it all, just not on IE11. So I dont see a point changing your mentioned values when it already works like that on all browsers except IE11. With that script, nothing stutters, since it disabled smooth scrolling that breaks it in first page on Edge and IE10. My question was: what should be changed to get it working on all browsers including IE11.

Comment: The normalizing shouldn't change the behavior in other browsers, and you can do it in your current script too. The "unit" of `deltaY` and `wheelDelta` is _line_ in other browsers, whereas in IEs it is _pixel_. That's why you get jumpy scrolling in IE, when you're not normalizing the scrolling amount. I thought jQuery should normalize this, but obviously it doesn't. Just log `wheelDelta` to the console, and you'll understand what I mean.

Comment: @Teemu Ok I figured it out now. I used the same script I posted in my question for IE10 and Edge, but for IE11, I had to change event.wheelDelta to event.deltaY. And also change the '-' in window.scrollTo function to '+'. If you could change one of your comments to answer I would be happy to mark that as the correct answer, otherwise I answer my own question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I Had the same issue and I came up with this using event listener "wheel", I hope it helps.

```
if (evt.type == "wheel") {
        // delta or detail from event 
      var delta = evt.wheelDelta ? evt.wheelDelta / 10 : evt.originalEvent.detail || evt.originalEvent.deltaY) / 3;
        // if Firefox 
        var fireFoxAgent = navigator.userAgent.match(/Firefox/i) != null;
        // if IE
        var ieUserAgent = navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./) != null;

        if (fireFoxAgent) {
            this.transY -= -40 * delta;                   
        }
        else if(ieUserAgent)
        {
            this.transY -= -delta;
        }
        else
        {
            this.transY -= delta;
        }

        if (this.transY > this.minY) {
            //down
            this.transY = this.minY;
        }
        if (this.transY < this.maxY) {
            //up
            this.transY = this.maxY;
        }


    }
    evt.preventDefault();
```

I called it via jQuery

```
      $('#scroll-content').bind("wheel", function(event) {
            scrollAreas[0].handleEvent(event);
        });
```

Comment: Instead of sniffing the UA, you should be reading [event.deltaMode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent/deltaMode) property as FF sets it to `WheelEvent.DOM_DELTA_LINE`. See